# Cant Knit to pdf or html

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse

I'm trying to knit to pdf

I've installed the tinytex and kakble extra packages but it does not knit to any desired format

see the error in the screenshot below

is there something I'm doing wrong or a script or something

Kindly assist me to fix this ... although I'm new to rmd.

[image]

Comment: You do not define the object `error_per_server_lst` in any R chunk before. Objects in the global environment are omitted during knitering to ensure reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `error_per_server_lst`, it says that the object does not exists.